# split rod in two at a random point and then split the two parts again into another

Tags: probability

I have a rod of unit length which I split into 2 parts at a random point. Lets call the larger part **X** and the smaller part **Y**.

If we then split **X** into 2 parts at a random point and call **X1** the larger part of this division and **X2** the smaller part of this division.

and we also split **Y** into 2 parts at a random point and call **Y1** the larger part of this division and **Y2** the smaller part of this division.

What is the probability that **X2** > **Y1**?

I get that the answer is 50% but when I try test it in a python program I get around 47.5%

Can somebody tell me if the answer is indeed 50% and if not can you explain why it isnt?

Answer (score 0):

Let the first break point be $U_{1}\sim\mathrm{Unif}(0,1),$ and conditional on $U_{1}<1/2$ (by symmetry, we might as well condition on this), we get that $Y$ has length $U_{1}$ and $X$ has length $1-U_{1}.$ Note that conditional on $U_{1}<1/2,$ the distribution of $U_{1}$ is just $\mathrm{Unif}(0,1/2).$ Now let $U_{2}\sim\mathrm{Unif}(0,U_{1}),$ and $U_{3}\sim\mathrm{Unif}(U_{1},1)$, and again by symmetry, we should condition on $U_{2}<U_{1}/2$ and $U_{3}<(U_{1}+1)/2,$ so that $Y_{1}$ has length $U_{1}-U_{2}$ and $X_{2}$ has length $U_{3}-U_{1}.$

Then for $U_{1}=u<1/2,$ the length of $Y_{1}$ is distributed $\mathrm{Unif}(u/2,u),$ and $X_{2}$ has length distributed $\mathrm{Unif}(0,(1-u)/2)$. Since $(1-u)/2>u$ if and only if $u<1/3,$ we have: \begin{align*}P(\ell(Y_{1})<\ell(X_{2})|U_{1}=u)&=\int_{u/2}^{(1-u)/2}\int_{u/2}^{\min\{u,x\}}\frac{2}{u}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{1-u}\mathrm{d}x\\&=\frac{4}{u(1-u)}\int_{u/2}^{(1-u)/2}\min\{u,x\}-u/2\;\mathrm{d}x,
\\(\text{if }u<1/3)&=\frac{4}{u(1-u)}\left(\int_{u/2}^{u}x\;\mathrm{d}x+u((1-u)/2-u)-\frac{u}{2}\frac{1-2u}{2}\right)
\\&=\frac{4}{u(1-u)}\left(\frac{3u^{2}}{8}+\frac{u-3u^{2}}{2}+\frac{2u^{2}-u}{4}\right)\\&=\frac{4}{u(1-u)}\frac{-5u^{2}+2u}{8}=\frac{2-5u}{2(1-u)},
\\(\text{if }1/3<u<1/2)&=\frac{4}{u(1-u)}\int_{u/2}^{(1-u)/2}x-u/2\;\mathrm{d}x
\\&=\frac{4}{u(1-u)}\left(\frac{(2u-1)^{2}}{8}\right)=\frac{(2u-1)^{2}}{2u(1-u)}
\end{align*}

Then the probability should be $$P(\ell(Y_{1})<\ell(X_{2}))=\int_{0}^{1/3}\frac{2-5u}{1-u}\mathrm{d}u+\int_{1/3}^{1/2}\frac{(2u-1)^{2}}{u(1-u)}\mathrm{d}u$$ (recall that the density of $U_{1}$ is $2$ on $(0,1/2)$). The first term is $5(u-1)+3\ln(1-u)|_{0}^{1/3}=5/3-3\ln(3/2)$, and the second term is $-4u-\ln(1-u)+\ln(u)|_{1/3}^{1/2}=\ln(2)-2/3.$ Then we have $1-\ln(27/16)\approx0.47675,$ which seems to match the answer you were getting with your Python program.

Comment: As for the intuition, I think that we tend to discount the idea that $\ell(Y_{1})$ can be greater than $\ell(X_{1})$: if $\ell(Y)=0.45,$ $\ell(X)=0.55,$ then $\ell(Y_{1})=0.05$ means that $\ell(Y_{2})=0.4,$ and in this setting, $P(\ell(X_{1})>0.4)$ is only $\approx 55\%.$ I think this doesn't gel with the naive intuition about this problem, and this might lead us to think that the original problem would have solution 1/2, rather than something strictly less than this.